# the CookieContainer option is disappeared from the RestClientOptions in version 109.1 so the authentication doesn't work anymore

Tags: restsharp

I've upgraded the project to use RestSharp 109.1, and since then the authentication doesn't work and I can't find my authentication cookie.

with RestSharp 108.2 this restclientoptions worked:

```
var options108 = new RestClientOptions($"{realm.ConfigSource}")
                {
                    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (restclientsender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
                    MaxTimeout = -1,
                    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
                };
```

with RestSharp 109.1 the CookieContainer option is missing and I have to use these options:

```
var options109 = new RestClientOptions($"{realm.ConfigSource}")
                {
                    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (restclientsender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
                    MaxTimeout = -1,
                };
```

the following code with 108 returns 1 cookie in the restresponse, with 109 it is 0.

```
var restclient = new RestClient(options109);

                var loginrequest = new RestRequest();
                loginrequest.Resource = "login";
                loginrequest.Method = Method.Post;
                loginrequest.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
                loginrequest.AddParameter("username", realm.Username);
                loginrequest.AddParameter("password", realm.Password);
                
                var loginresult = await restclient.ExecuteAsync(loginrequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
                log.LogInformation($"StatusCode:  {loginresult.StatusCode}");
                log.LogInformation($"IsSuccessful:  {loginresult.IsSuccessful}");
                log.LogInformation($"Cookies.Count:  {loginresult.Cookies.Count}");
```

So where is my authentication cookie and how to get it??

Added the following line to the request, but still no cookie.
loginrequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

Answer (score 0):

Moot point. It seems the cookie container option is not needed in the newer version of RestSharp.
The basic problem is that the authentication fails on .NET 7.0 with the RestSharp 109.0.1 so there is no cookie anywhere anyways. (this bug is being investigated currently)

Comment: Btw the response will contain the cookie you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get fixed with this code:

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
client = new RestClient(new RestClientOptions()
{
   BaseUrl = new Uri(Url.baseUrl),                
   CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
   ConfigureMessageHandler = (messageHandler) =>
   {
     ((System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler)messageHandler).UseCookies = true;
     ((System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler)messageHandler).CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
     return messageHandler;
   }
 });
```

That is the only way I made it work.